# Regex to match string either not exact string or pattern

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to match a pattern with this regex

```
"^[a-zA-Z]{1}[a-zA-Z0-9\\s_]*(?<![Ii][Dd]|[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee][Dd][Dd][Aa][Tt][Ee]|[Cc][Rr][Ee][Aa][Tt][Ee][Dd][Bb][Yy]|[Mm][Oo][Dd][Ii][Ff][Ii][Ee][Dd][Dd][Aa][Tt][Ee]|[Mm][Oo][Dd][Ii][Ff][Ii][Ee][Dd][Bb][Yy]|[Oo][Rr][Gg][Ii][Dd])$"
```

This pattern should match any string that does not start with a number or has anything else other than space, underscore, characters and numbers along with that it should also fail if the string is exactly `ID` or `CreatedDate` or `CreatedBy` or `ModifiedDate` or `ModifiedBy` or `OrgID`. It should also check that the static strings are checked without case sensitivity.

- Pass - "Bob9 Tom"
- Fail - "9Bob Tom"
- Fail - "ID"
- Pass - "Tom Tom"
- Pass - "Tom ID"
- Pass - "IDTom"
- Pass - "TomID"

Comment: Are values beginning with a space or underscore valid?

Comment: No that is not valid. I've got something that I'm updating in the question. Just verify it please.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a negative lookahead at the start to check for the string which won't contain the exact string mentioned. `(?i)` called case-insensitive modifier which forces the regex engine to do a case-insensitive match.

```
@"(?i)^(?!(?:ID|CreatedDate|CreatedBy|ModifiedDate|ModifiedBy|OrgID)$)[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9\s_]*"
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lR1dS5/1)

Comment: Thanks. I did this with negative look behind. Almost similar to yours. But to make the static string case insensitive I had to include all possible case for each string. I've updated my question. Just guide me whether that is correct or wrong. If there is any other better way let me know.

Comment: added `(?i)` to do a case-insensitive match.

Answer (score 1):

This pattern should match any string

- that does not start with a number

  ```
  ^\D
  ```
- or has anything else other than space, underscore, characters and numbers

  ```
  ^\D[ _a-zA-Z0-9]*$
  ```
- along with that it should also fail if the string is exactly `ID` or `CreatedDate` or `CreatedBy` or `ModifiedDate` or `ModifiedBy` or `OrgID`.

  ```
  ^(?!(?:CreatedDate|CreatedBy|ModifiedDate|ModifiedBy|OrgID)$)\D[ _a-zA-Z0-9]*$
  ```
- It should also check that the static strings are checked without case sensitivity.

  ```
  ^(?!(?:(?i)CreatedDate|CreatedBy|ModifiedDate|ModifiedBy|OrgID)$)\D[ _a-zA-Z0-9]*$
  ```

Notes

- The last step could be substituted by making the entire regex case-insensitive.
- `^\D` *literally* means "should not start with a number". If you meant "...but the starting character should still be one of `[ _a-zA-Z0-9]`", then `^\D` would have to change to `^[a-zA-Z]`.
- if you switch the entire expression to case-insensitive (and I don't see why you wouldn't), youc can replace all `a-zA-Z` with `a-z`.